# How to take decision on basis of the value of all repeating element in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, mapping, xslt-grouping

I have the following XML Input and I want to perform some transformation on it.

**Input XML:**

```
<itemDetails>
    <itemShipmentDate>2017-06-19</itemShipmentDate>
    <itemBillingDate>2017-06-15</itemBillingDate>
    <itemLines>
         <itemLine>
            <itemId>1</itemId>
            <itemQuantity>0</itemQuantity>
         </itemLine>
         <itemLine>
            <itemId>2</itemId>
            <itemQuantity>0</itemQuantity>
         </itemLine>
         <itemLine>
            <itemId>3</itemId>
            <itemQuantity>0</itemQuantity>
         </itemLine>
         <itemLine>
            <itemId>4</itemId>
            <itemQuantity>0</itemQuantity>
         </itemLine>
         <itemLine>
            <itemId>5</itemId>
            <itemQuantity>0</itemQuantity>
         </itemLine>
    </itemLines>         
</itemDetails>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to check that IF the "Quantity" tags in all the itemLine is equal to zero, then in the output one field i.e. "AllItemsQuantityFlag" value should be "Yes, If one of the quantity tags is not zero then the output should be "No".
So, kind of like IF else scenarios.

So, In above mentioned Input case, we will have following output:

**Desired Output:**

```
<OutputDetails xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <itemSDate>2017-06-19</itemSDate>
   <itemBDate>2017-06-15</itemBDate>
   <AllItemsQuantityFlag>Yes</AllItemsQuantityFlag>
</OutputDetails>
```

Following is my XSLT Sheet:

**XSLT Sheet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="/itemDetails">
                <OutputDetails>
                    <itemSDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="itemShipmentDate"/>
                    </itemSDate>
                    <itemBDate>
                                   <xsl:value-of select="itemBillingDate"/>
                          </itemBDate>
                <xsl:for-each select="itemLines/itemLine">                           
                <xsl:choose>        
                    <xsl:when test="IF All Zeros">          
                        <AllItemsQuantityFlag>Yes</AllItemsQuantityFlag>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <AllItemsQuantityFlag>No</AllItemsQuantityFlag>

                    </xsl:otherwise>

                </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
                 </OutputDetails>
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could somebody please advice on how to do it. I just want this field "" to appear once in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a check `some ... satisfies` and convert the boolean value to a number:

```
            <AllItemsQuantityFlag>
                <xsl:value-of
                  select="number(some $il in itemLines/itemLine satisfies $il/itemQuantity != 0) "/>
            </AllItemsQuantityFlag>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But If I want to check it in a slight different way, If there is all zero then I want to write "Yes" and if there is "1" in atleast one input field, then i want to write "No" in the field. Sorry , I forgot to mention it earlier.. I have edited the question now. Can you please have a look now ??

Answer (score 1):

Or shortly:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(itemLines/itemLine/itemQuantity!=0)"/>
```

---

Note that "not zero" includes empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It works, But If I want to check it in a slight different way, If there is all zero then I want to write "Yes" and if there is "1" in atleast one input field, then i want to write "No" in the field. Sorry , I forgot to mention it earlier.. I have edited the question now..

Comment: @omerkhalid Then use: `<xsl:value-of select="if(itemLines/itemLine/itemQuantity!=0) then 'Yes' else 'No'"/>`